Cron job in Jenkins with choice params doesn't work
I am trying to write a jenkins cron job with some paratmers of type choiceParam() and it doent work together.
How do i Have choce params and run the job in every 6 hours?
I am trying do it via jCASC, where i have a .groovy which having the script below, while it runs .jenikins file.
    properties {
        pipelineTriggers {
            triggers {
                cron {
                    spec('* h/6 * * *')
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    parameters {
        stringParam('JENKINS_FILE_BRANCH', 'branch name', 'The Branch with the Jenkins File')
        choiceParam('SERVICE_NAME', ['service1' 'serivce 2'], 'Select a service to check the status for')
        choiceParam('DC', ['DC1', 'CD2'], 'Select a service to check the status for')
    }

and when i push it it throws the error as below
ERROR: Could not instantiate {spec= h/6 * * } for hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

A corrected version of your syntax would be spec('* H/6 * * *').
This will trigger the job every 6 hours, but the exact minute will vary to help balance the load.

If this is not what you want, can you be more precise on what are you expecting from the cron ?
